# iPad app is exiting out after inactivity

Tags: ios

Have had reports of iPad application exiting after anywhere from 20 minutes to 3 hours of user inactivity, meaning no touch events. The app is business facing so it typically is in the foreground 24/7. This hasn't ever been reported in years but has been reported by a few clients across several devices running iOS 11.2 and 11.3 in the last couple of days.

More info:

- `idleTimer` is disabled, so the device isn't auto-locking.
- There are no crash reports being generated for these instances; using Fabric Crashlytics, and there are other crash reports being uploaded for unrelated issues.
- There are no `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning` or `didReceiveMemoryWarning` being reported that would indicate an Out-Of-Memory shutdown.
- There is no indication that any of `applicationWillTerminate`, `applicationDidEnterBackground`, or `applicationWillResignActive` are being called before the app exit, so the user is not doing it.

Given that it doesn't immediately appear to be a crash, an OOM, or user-terminated, what are other scenarios that would cause an app to exit out, possibly related to user-inactivity? Any known, similar issues in iOS 11, or further troubleshooting? I have not been able to reproduce, but can tell the reports are legitimate from the device logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have since witnessed it occur on an iPad running iOS 11.3.1, which would explain the behavior that was reported. The iPad has auto-lock disabled and will be running for hours at a time, and then it will inexplicably go to a black screen with the activity indicator spinning wheel for ~5-10 seconds before completely locking. Then I have to unlock with my passcode and I land on the home screen.

There are many posts about this "black screen spinning wheel" and many answers indicating it was resolved in iOS 11.2 but clearly that's not the case. This happens to me while running the Inbox by Google app but I can only imagine it's what my users are experiencing.

Adding the Console logs from when this occurred:

```
default 14:54:49.449536 -0700   mobilewatchdog  333328722246208: watchdog: GetIsAlive for service com.apple.backboardd failed with error 268451843. now: 333328722243666 last_success: 333208713010833 last_crash: 327796975020291 num_crashes: 0
default 14:54:49.449895 -0700   mobilewatchdog  333328722458250: watchdog: com.apple.backboardd not responding to query at time 333328722243666; forcing a crash
default 14:54:49.463537 -0700   ReportCrash Stackshot requested by mobilewatchdog, code: faded321, reason: <private>
default 14:54:49.470163 -0700   ReportCrash starting prolongation transaction timer
default 14:54:49.491050 -0700   ReportCrash Unknown KCDATA 922, size 4, flags 922
default 14:54:49.842516 -0700   ReportCrash Saved type '288(288)' report (59 of max 100) at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/stacks+backboardd-2018-06-11-145449.ips
default 14:54:49.865879 -0700   mobilewatchdog  Connection interrupted!
default 14:54:49.867034 -0700   CommCenter  #I CTServerConnection from pid 2287 has closed (conn=0x101d9c990)
default 14:54:49.867424 -0700   SpringBoard Terminating since backboardd has gone away.
```

According to the CrashReport from the device logs the exception is `0xfaded321` which is a Watchdog timeout. Being that it's an internal error and happened to both of the apps I happened to use today, seems like an iOS bug that I'll have to report.

Comment: I have experienced this "soft reboot" a few times on my iOS devices too, but couldn't really figure out what causes it. Sometimes it happened to me while typing in the Facebook Messenger app; the whole UI froze for a few seconds, then the screen went black with the activity indicator, and then I was back at the lock screen. I think it's some bug in iOS itself, like a deadlock in the window server, which causes the system to kill do this soft reboot. I'd recommend checking out the device logs for suspicious error messages from system services.

Comment: Thanks @TamásZahola. Where do you see system logs? I looked at Window->Devices->Device Logs through Xcode and it's just showing crashes and CPU Usage warnings, but nothing from this month.

Comment: Plug in the device to your Mac, and open Console.app. On the sidebar you should see your device; select it, and now you should see the system logs in real time.

Comment: Thanks @TamásZahola that helped, I've updated my answer. I can see mobilewatchdog is forcing due to com.apple.backboardd inactivity but I don't know what that is or why it'd happen. I updated my answer.

Comment: backboardd is the iOS system UI process (OS menu, control center, etc.). You should raise the issue at bugreport.apple.com. Maybe try iOS 12 beta to see if the issue have been resolved there.